# Automatically infer return type using enum parameter

Tags: java, generics, enums

Is it possible to automatically infer the return type if I give an Enum as parameter to a method in Java?

I would like to be able to support these calls by making getValue generic and using information in the Enum

```
String myval = obj.getValue(MyEnum.Field1)
int myval2 = obj.getValue(MyEnum.Field2)
```

**Current solution**

My current solution does like this:

`String val = typeRow.getColumnValueGen(TYPEGODKENDCRM.COLUMN_TYPEGODKENDNR, String.class)`

It's for accessing columns in a ORM representation of a table. I known that this field is a string, I would like to avoid having to tell it at every call.

Comment: Can't understand your question. Which method you are talking about? Is there any template for it?

Comment: It's a general question on whether I can store information in an Enum, in this case MyEnum, and use this for defining a generic method which infers the correct return type based on this information

Comment: If you know the types at compile time, consider adding getXValue (i.e. getStringValue) methods? No casting, but at the cost of more methods.

Comment: mwittrock, that's a good suggestion, I'll do that instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to automatically infer the return type if I give an Enum as parameter to a method in Java?

No. You can't overload methods by return type in Java, and if you wanted something like:

```
public <T> T getValue(MyEnum enumValue)
```

there's no way for the compiler to infer `T` based on the argument. Type inference can work in *some* cases, but not like this. There's no way for the compiler to examine some aspect of the argument and infer or even validate the type based on that value.

Aside from anything else, what would you expect it to do if the argument *weren't* a compile-time constant?

```
MyEnum x = getEnumValue();
// Is this valid or not?
String myVal = obj.getValue(x);
```

Basically you would *have* to cast the return value... and in the case of `int`, you'd need to cast to `Integer` rather than `int`, and then let auto-unboxing do the rest.

Personally I'd just create multiple methods:

```
String x = obj.getString(...);
int y = obj.getInt(...);
```

That leaves no room for ambiguity, doesn't require any cleverness with generics etc.

Comment: My old solution did like this:

typeRow.getColumnValueGen(TYPEGODKENDCRM.COLUMN_TYPEGODKENDNR, String.class)

As you see it's for accessing columns in a ORM representation of a table. I known that this field is a string, I would like to avoid having to tell it at every call.

Comment: @PerStilling: Why not just have separate methods? getStringValue, getIntValue etc? (I'll add that into my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

In a word: No. You'd have to declare getValue as returning Object and then cast the returned object to the actual type. Not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Object getValue(MyEnum returnType) {
    if (returnType == MyEnum.STRING) {
        String myString = ...
        return myString;
    }
    else if (returnType == MyEnum.INT) {
        int myInt = ...
        return Integer(myInt);
    }
}
```

then:

```
String myval = (String) obj.getValue(MyEnum.Field1);
int myval2 = ( (Integer) obj.getValue(MyEnum.Field2) ).intValue();
```

Note that you must use reference types for this to work, so you need `Integer`s instead of `int`.

By the way, I wouldn't recommend this.  If you'd like to give more information about what you're trying to do, we might be able to suggest a better way of going about it.

Comment: I want to avoid the all the ugly type casting, that's the point of wanting a generic solution.

Comment: I think you need to make your question a little clearer then.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: unless you have the same input parameters you have few choices for polymorphism