# Selenium Java Lambda Implementation for Explicit Waits

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, lambda

I am trying to implement Java Lambda concept for selenium webdriver waits. I need to convert custom webdriver wait something like this

```
  (new WebDriverWait(driver(), 5))
            .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                    return d.findElement(By.linkText(""));
                }
            });
```

to

```
 (new WebDriverWait(driver(), 5)).until((driver) -> driver.findElement(By.linkText("")));
```

But it does not matches the functional interface of 'until' refers to and throws error.

So i tried passing the Lambda as it supports.

Attempt1

```
Predicate<WebDriver> isVisible = (dr) -> dr.findElement(
     By.linkText("")).isDisplayed();
     webDriverWait.until(isVisible);
```

It kind of works but is not what i require because it returns only void.

Need your help or advice on this.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Heres the error i got "Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to boolean"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with your syntax.The below worked perfectly for me

```
WebElement wer = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until((WebDriver dr1) -> dr1.findElement(By.id("q")));
```

Your code Problem

```
 //What is this driver() is this a function that returns the driver or what
 //You have to defined the return type of driver variable in until() function
 //And you cant use the same  variable names in both new WebdriverWait() and until() see my syntax

(new WebDriverWait(driver(), 5)).until((driver) -> driver.findElement(By.linkText("")));
```

Comment: Added the type declaration for the Lambda expression as you suggested and it worked as expected. Question : Wouldn't the type is automatically inferred?

Comment: Then accept it as an answer as it would be helpful for others

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502654/automatically-infer-return-type-using-enum-parameter)

Answer (score 4):

Because the method `WebDriverWait#until` is overloaded:  [until(Function)](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until(com.google.common.base.Function)) and [until(Predicate)](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until(com.google.common.base.Predicate)), the compiler cannot infer the type of the argument to the lambda method.

In this case, both functional interfaces `Function` and `Predicate` take a single argument, which in this case is either `<? super T>` or `T`.  Therefore the declarative syntax is needed here:

`new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until((WebDriver dr1) -> dr1.findElement(By.id("q")));`

Note that the lambda return types do not help the compiler to distinguish these cases.  In your example, since `#findElement` returns `WebElement`, this is conceptually enough to distinguish a `Function` from a `Predicate`, but apparently not enough for the compiler.

See also:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html#parameter-types